# Rename with random numbers

Tags: c#, random, foreach, rename, generate

I was trying to make smth like this...
Basically im trying to shuffle music by their names.
Everything works nicely, but i was wondering if theres a way for tihs random funcion not to repeat same numbers?

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     button1.Enabled = true;

     DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
     count = dir.GetFiles().Length;
     label3.Text = "Files loaded: " + count.ToString();
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
     FileInfo[] infos = d.GetFiles("*.mp3");
     int i = 1;

     foreach (FileInfo f in infos)
     {
         File.Move(f.FullName, Path.Combine(f.DirectoryName, i + ". " + f.Name));
         i = rnd.Next(1, count+1);
     }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/61338/generate-random-numbers-without-repetitions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
string path = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.mp3");
// Create list of shuffled numbers
var shuffledNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, files.Length).ToArray().OrderBy(i => Guid.NewGuid());
// put the shuffled numbers into a stack
var indexes = new Stack<int>(shuffledNumbers);
foreach(var file in files) {
    // extract first item from the stack
    var index = indexes.Pop();
    // move file
    File.Move(file, Path.Combine(path, $"{index}. {Path.GetFileName(file)}"));
}
```

Basically I shuffle an array of sequential numbers using `Guid.NewGuid` as a order key.

Every time `OrderBy` will compare two items of the array, it will get a different, totally random value.

Using a Stack allows me to just pop the next number without having to use an indexer variable (but it's totally fine if you prefer that way).

Comment: I found this very helpfull, it does the job!

Comment: `Every time OrderBy will compare two items of the array, it will get a different, totally random value.` No, it won't. While GUIDs would be unique, order might stay the same. F.e. UID pairs (12345, 23456) and (54321, 65432), while being unique, produce the same ordering

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is by creating a List of your files, where you put all the names. Then you shuffle that list by using something like the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) which gives you a guaranteed random sequence. Then you can just do a regular for-loop over the List and rename the files according to your counting variable.

This way, instead of trying to generate random numbers to rename objects, you just shuffle them like a deck of cards and rename them based on the new order. Also, note that a Fisher-Yates shuffle is O(n) as there is only a single execution needed to randomize any set of values.

Example code, based on your code:

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
List<FileInfo> infos = new List<FileInfo>(d.GetFiles("*.mp3"));

infos.FisherYatesShuffle(rnd);

for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; ++i)
{
    File.Move(f.FullName, Path.Combine(f.DirectoryName, i + ". " + f.Name));
}
```

And some (untested) Fisher-Yates-Shuffle algorithm I just hacked together as an extension method for lists:

```
public static void FisherYatesShuffle<T>(this IList<T> list, Random random)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        int index = rnd.Next(0, list.Count - i);
        int lastIndex = list.Count - i - 1;
        T value = list[index];
        {
            T temp = list[num1];
            list[num1] = list[num2];
            list[num2] = temp;
        }
        list.RemoveAt(lastIndex);
        list.Add(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am in agreement with Max's answer. If anyone finds it useful, I have a Nuget package called RandomShuffler:

DataJuggler.RandomShuffler.Core        (Dot Net Core)

DataJuggler.Core.RandomShuffler        (.Net Framework)

The difference between a Shuffler and a Random Number Generator is a shuffler pulls all the times, like a deck of cards and leads to more even distribution where random numbers can even out over several million years or more.

[image]

Get your min and max bounds of your List Or Array

```
using DataJuggler.RandomShuffler.Core;

int min = 0;
int max = List.Count -1;

// Create a new instance of a 'RandomShuffler' object.
Shuffler = new RandomShuffler(min, max, 1, 3);
```

This creates a list between your min and max, and the 1 as the 3rd parameter, means only 1 set (no duplicates).

Then each time you need a need a new value simply call Shuffler.PullNextItem:

```
// pull the next White value
int index = Shuffler.PullNextItem();

var songToPlay = List[index]; // not sure what properties you need
```

It automatically shuffles if you run out, and there are also overrides for cards.